# Android BroadcastReceiver is not called when bluetooth scan

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I've a terrible problem with `broadcastreceiver`. When i want to scan `bluetooth` my around but i see that broadcastreceiver is not called. I suspect this happens for my android version which is api 23 as shown here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190188. There is no problem when i run my app in mobile phones which the apis are below from 23
It is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    // take an instance of BluetoothAdapter - Bluetooth radio
    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    myBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();
    if(myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        onBtn.setEnabled(false);
        offBtn.setEnabled(false);
        listBtn.setEnabled(false);
        findBtn.setEnabled(false);
        text.setText("Status: not supported");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support Bluetooth",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        onBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOn);
        onBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                on(v);
            }
        });

        offBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOff);
        offBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                off(v);
            }
        });

        listBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.paired);
        listBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                list(v);
            }
        });

        findBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
        findBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                find(v);
            }
        });

        myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // create the arrayAdapter that contains the BTDevices, and set it to the ListView
        BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String address = BTArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("address",address);
                Log.e("address",address);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void on(View view){
    if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            text.setText("Status: Enabled");
        } else {
            text.setText("Status: Disabled");
        }
    }
}

public void list(View view){
    // get paired devices
    pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // put it's one to the adapter
    if(pairedDevices.size()!=0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress());
           // Log.e("name",device.getName())
        Log.e("name","men");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Show Paired Devices",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no any device",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // i can't see any log
        Log.e("action","show");
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.e("address",device.getAddress() + device.getName());
            // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
            BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getAddress());
            BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};


public void find(View view) {
    if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
        myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cancel",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        BTArrayAdapter.clear();
        myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void off(View view){
    myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
    text.setText("Status: Disconnected");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned off",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("bluetooth","destroy");
    unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Please, write your permissions

Comment: These are my permisiions  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />